# multiple file upload form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm currently messing around with a kind of blogpost creator for which I want to enable the possibilty to upload and embed pictures. Problem is that the form I'm using is generated via JavaScript which means I can't have two seperate forms for the upload and the blogpost itsself.

I'm trying it this way at the moment:
When the user hits "upload & embed" a new input with type="file" is generated beneath the textarea for the blogpost and the selected file name is used as a source in a image I paste into the textarea at current location. Problem is that I can't check if I already have a file which is named that way, which may lead to conflicts when only using the filename I got from the selection of the file input.

Can anyone tell if there is a smarter way to do this?

Comment: you can use my super sweet flie upload library to create a drag and drop area that you can use to upload multiple files https://github.com/Pamblam/fileUpload

Comment: filename = realname + math.rand + file_extend

Comment: vico might be a solution, but i hope there are more consistent ones

Comment: if you dont want to do a file check with php then thats how you want to do it. what system are you using anyway? just plain php?